# If always false, why?

Tags: php

I have a loop:

```
for ($p=1; $p<=$ncarts; $p++) {
    $contador_pontos_cartela[$p] = 0;
    for ($g=1; $g<=$quantidade_sorteada; $g++) {
       foreach ($numeros_cartela[$p] as $w) {
           echo "Valor de w: {$w} <br>";
           echo "Valor de sorted: {$sorted[$g]} <br>";
           if ($w == $sorted[$g]){
              echo "truue";
              $contador_pontos_cartela[$p] += 1;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

And

```
$ncarts = 3; 
$quantidade_sorteada = 3; 
$numeros_cartela[1] = array(1, 3); 
$numeros_cartela[2] = array (5, 7); 
$numeros_cartela[3] = array(9, 11); 
$sorted[1] = 1; 
$sorted[2] = 3; 
$sorted[3] = 5; `
```

I inserted that `echo $w` and `echo $sorted[$g]` to see if them values were correct. And the aswer is; YES. The output of that `echo` is:

```
Valor de w: 1 
Valor de sorted: 1 
Valor de w: 3 
Valor de sorted: 1 
Valor de w: 1 
Valor de sorted: 3 
Valor de w: 3 
Valor de sorted: 3 
Valor de w: 1 
Valor de sorted: 5 
Valor de w: 3 
Valor de sorted: 5 
Valor de w: 5 
Valor de sorted: 1 
Valor de w: 7 
Valor de sorted: 1 
Valor de w: 5 
Valor de sorted: 3 
Valor de w: 7 
Valor de sorted: 3 
Valor de w: 5 
Valor de sorted: 5 
Valor de w: 7 
Valor de sorted: 5 
Valor de w: 9 
Valor de sorted: 1 
Valor de w: 11 
Valor de sorted: 1 
Valor de w: 9 
Valor de sorted: 3 
Valor de w: 11 
Valor de sorted: 3 
Valor de w: 9 
Valor de sorted: 5 
Valor de w: 11 
Valor de sorted: 5
```

In other words, I have 3 positive results. Where `$w` is equal `$sorted` (on the 1,1; 3,3; and 5,5)
But `if ($w == $sorted[$g])` never becomes true... You know, I have a echo inside `if`; `echo "truue";` and this never is printed.

Can anybody see the problem?

Comment: $sorted is an array with this values: $sorted[1] = 1; $sorted[2] = 3; $sorted[3] = 5; Excuse me, I forgot it. Just edit the post.

Comment: var_dump($w, $sorted[$g]) before the if statement. That will show you what the exact contents of those variables are. i am puzzled.

Comment: string(3) "1 " string(1) "1" string(3) "3 " string(1) "1" string(3) "1 " string(1) "3" string(3) "3 " string(1) "3" string(3) "1 " string(1) "5" string(3) "3 " string(1) "5" string(3) "5 " string(1) "1" string(3) "7 " string(1) "1" string(3) "5 " string(1) "3" string(3) "7 " string(1) "3" string(3) "5 " string(1) "5" string(3) "7 " string(1) "5" string(3) "9 " string(1) "1" string(4) "11 " string(1) "1" string(3) "9 " string(1) "3" string(4) "11 " string(1) "3" string(3) "9 " string(1) "5" string(4) "11 " string(1) "5"

Comment: can you try this in your if statement and give me a feedback.. `if(in_array($w, $sorted) == true)` what will be the answer?

Comment: why there's a space between value and double quote ??

Comment: there is the answer - different length strings. do a trim.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but I get 'truue' sometimes, check it out here: [http://3v4l.org/DRvMu](http://3v4l.org/DRvMu)

Comment: You have strings of different lengths there rather than integers. You need to clean up your data/input.

Comment: [Your code works](http://3v4l.org/SlHso)

Comment: in the link you have provided,there's nothing wrong,the values are different that why true is not printing, check it once again

Comment: your code does not reproduce the problem

Comment: OK. I think I understood. I have a space in some input, using the trim() I will remove that space. But, where is the space, I'm not seeing. Thank YOU GUYS!

Comment: @user790454 There is no link in the post, what do you mean?

Comment: oh not to you bro, @webeno

Comment: @vascowhite and webeno On my server it is returning only false... ??

Comment: Guys, I thank you so much! I'vnt noted the space... I used the trim() and the program worked. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your var_dump():-

```
string(3) "1 " string(1) "1" string(3) "3 " string(1) "1" string(3) "1 " string(1) "3" string(3) "3 " string(1) "3" string(3) "1 " string(1) "5" string(3) "3 " string(1) "5" string(3) "5 " string(1) "1" string(3) "7 " string(1) "1" string(3) "5 " string(1) "3" string(3) "7 " string(1) "3" string(3) "5 " string(1) "5" string(3) "7 " string(1) "5" string(3) "9 " string(1) "1" string(4) "11 " string(1) "1" string(3) "9 " string(1) "3" string(4) "11 " string(1) "3" string(3) "9 " string(1) "5" string(4) "11 " string(1) "5"
```

Shows that you are not getting clean data/input. You are trying to compare "1  " with "1". Take a look at where these values come from and ensure that they are cleaned up. eg use `trim()` to remove any unwanted white space or cast them to integers.

This problem often occurs when using data that has originally come from user input and has not been properly filtered.

I would recommend you do that with your source data, but as a quick fix, you could do it in your loop using [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/trim).